# How to import "import {authConfig} from '../configs/auth';" in NightWatch.js (Datadriven)

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am working with Nightwatch.js framework, I have referred this code.But I don't know how to import `import {authConfig}  from '../configs/auth';` in NightWatch.js.
See my code's [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvnbx.png)

Comment: Please elaborate your question with relevant code.

Comment: I have written a script with data-driven in Nightwatch.js but I don't know to import "import {authConfig}  from '../configs/auth';"  and I don't understand the meaning of this statement. You can click into Screenshot to more information about my code. Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

That's just test data for a hypothetical data-driven test. It has nothing to do with NightWatch.js itself. You'd import whatever data you need to run your own tests.